# AWS SimpleDB how to setup

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-simpledb

I can't find an option of SimpleDB on the management console.

Is there something I'm missing?

I'll be using it with an iOS App just for doing basic operations like adding/editing/deleting.

**Is DynamoDB a option I should consider?**

(Previously I was using Parse, so I'm looking for something as similar as possible)

Answer (score 2):

There never was a SimpleDB console. You always need a third party tool. There are [Java scratch pad](https://aws.amazon.com/code/JavaScript/1137) available by Amazon SimpleDB but they were last updated on 2010. I suggest you to use any third part tool like [SDBExplorer](http://www.sdbexplorer.com/). or any other tool from the [link](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/blog/amazon-simpledb-3rd-party-tools-updated/).

You can choose according to your requirement among these two amazon cloud database service.

**Amazon SimpleDB service** – Amazon SimpleDB can be useful for those who need a non-relational database for storage of smaller, non-structural data. Amazon SimpleDB has restricted storage size to 10GB per domain and it can achieve up to 25 writes/second. Amazon SimpleDB offers simplicity and flexibility. SimpleDB automatically indexes all data. Amazon SimpleDB pricing is based on your actual box usage. You can store any UTF-8 string data in Amazon SimpleDB.

**Amazon DynamoDB service** – Amazon DynamoDB can be useful for those who need a fast, highly scalable non-relational database. There is no limit on the storage size per table and you can specify how much request capability you require. Amazon DynamoDB offers good performance and incremental scalability. DynamoDB indexes only the primary key, which can be a composite primary key. DynamoDB is priced according to how much request capacity you have requested. You can store Strings and Numbers.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleDB is still being supported by AWS but the recommended AWS NoSQL datastoure is DynamoDB. You said you only need basic operations like add/edit/delete. DynamoDB supports all of that and you should consider using DynamoDB instead of SimpleDB.

Comment: Why should DynamoDB be used instead of SimpleDB? What are the benefits of that?

Comment: Because SimpleDB is mostly in maintenance mode (which means no new feature will be added but AWS will continue to support existing customer) and DynamoDB can cover the majority use cases of SimpleDB